# Mail filters like functionality in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, business-rules

For my new project, I need a functionality like mail filters. There will be a set of rules with associated actions. When an user submits a request, it needs to be passed through these rules for validation. In case any one of these rules matches, the corresponding action should be triggered (or, the model should be updated with a few more attributes). Just like mail filters.

And, these rules will be user specific and stored as ActiveRecord models.

Any pointers for existing gems?!

My ROR version is 2.3.8

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for validation at the controller level. What I would recommend is to add filters in your ApplicationController.

For example :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :is_logged_in
    def is_logged_in
        # ... do your stuff !
    end
end
```

What is great with this is :

- you can with ruby, as a OO language, create you own hierachy of classes, thus making your code easyly understandable, dry an all.
- having before filter, after filter ... look here for more infos http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html
- access the current controller and action : `controller.controller_name` and `controller.action_name`

Also, keep in mind that there are validation you should implement at the model level. ActiveRecord also provides a set of useful similar filters : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Comment: Marcel, Guess I was not clear in the original post. What I am looking for goes beyond validation. It is more like business rules. In a CRM application, if the request is from a particular company or for a particular product or based on timezone etc., assign to this group, set it to high priority etc.,

Comment: Yes Marcel! But not a full blown workflow system like Stonepath or something similar. Just simple rules check like mail filters. If a rule matches, do the corresponding action and exit. Otherwise go to the next rule. At the outset, it may sound like a workflow engine, but far simpler.

Comment: OK Shan, maybe you sould look around http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. I have skimmed through ruby-toolbox earlier, will check it on again.